# Apache HTTP Client loadTrustMaterial not working

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

First of all, There is no comment in source code.

`org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContextBuilder#loadTrustMaterial(org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.TrustStrategy)`

```java
public SSLContextBuilder loadTrustMaterial(
        final TrustStrategy trustStrategy) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    return loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy);
}
```

Here is the code will trigger confused behavior, It's same as apache offical demo [Apache Demo](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/httpclient5/examples/ClientCustomSSL.java)

```java
@Test
void customStrategy() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException, ParseException {

    SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom();
    sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> false);
    SSLContext sslcontext = sslContextBuilder.build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder sslConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder = SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create();
    sslConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.setSslContext(sslcontext);
    sslConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_2);
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = sslConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder poolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create();
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory);
    HttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager = poolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.build();

    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
    httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(httpClientConnectionManager);
    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();

    HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();

    CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.baidu.com"), clientContext);

    System.out.println("BODY-Length " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).length());

    SSLSession sslSession = clientContext.getSSLSession();

    System.out.println(sslSession.getPeerHost() + ":" + sslSession.getPeerPort());
}
```

The output is:

```
... ...
BODY-Length 2443
www.baidu.com:443
```

Even I directly return `false` in my custom TrustStrategy.

```java
sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> {
    throw new CertificateException();
});
```

That will interrupt the connection, But I don't think if a interface return false, But only interrupt when exception is correct usage.

Question:
Why return false is not working?
Thorw execption make me feeling wrong, Is that desigen for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see javadocs of `TrustStrategy#isTrusted`. If a `TrustStrategy` returns false from the `isTrusted` method the certificate verification is executed by the trust manager configured in the SSL context.